# PHP ldap_sort case insensitive

Tags: php

How I can use `ldap_search()` function in `PHP` with case insensitive sorting?

```
bool ldap_sort ( resource $link , resource $result , string $sortfilter )
```

I wanna use this style to sort ldap case insensitive:

```
$search_return = ldap_search($ldap_connection,$ldap_base,$search_filter);
ldap_sort($ldap_connection,$search_return,$value);
$entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection,$search_return);
```

what am I doing?

Comment: http://php.tonnikala.org/manual/sv/function.ldap-sort.php#81447  
this comment may help

Comment: i read that, but i want to do that with php ldap function.